# Capture organization names from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a bunch of rows that have text data in sentences. I am trying to apply entity extraction with Spacy to get organization and location.

I am able to pass in a string and get the entities. However if I apply tgat to a dataframe, it fails and here is the error. I am not sure if I wrote for loop incorrectly or not calling (X.text, X.label_) correctly? Is there a way to apply Spacy to a dataframe rows?

Dataframe not working:

```
import spacy 
from spacy import displacy
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
nlp = spacy.load("en") 

id1 = [1,2,3]
text = ['University of California has great research located in San Diego',np.NaN,'MIT is at Boston']
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':id1,'text':text})
df['text'] = df['text'].astype(str)
print(df)
'''
   id                                                              text
0   1  University of California has great research located in San Diego
1   2                                                               nan
2   3                                                  MIT is at Boston
'''
# works: passing nlp function from spacy 
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x)) # tokenized it
print(df['text'])

# fails
for row in df.iterrows():
    # getting: AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'label_'
    test = [(X.text, X.label_) for X in df['text']]
print(test)
```

String working:

```
sentence = 'University of California has great research located in San Diego'
result = nlp(sentence)
print([(X.text, X.label_) for X in result.ents])
'''
[('University of California', 'ORG'), ('San Diego', 'GPE')]
'''
```

How do I get results like this?:

```
   id                                                              text                                                 spacy_results         
0   1  University of California has great research located in San Diego [('University of California', 'ORG'), ('San Diego', 'GPE')]
1   2                                                               nan nan
2   3                                                  MIT is at Boston                         [('MIT', 'ORG'), ('Boston', 'GPE')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code :

```py
text = [[1, 'University of California has great research located in San Diego'],[2, 'MIT is at Boston']]
df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['id', 'text'])

def spacy_entity(df):    
    df1 = nlp(df)
    df2 = [[w.text,w.label_] for w in df1.ents]
    return df2

df1['new_text'] = df1['text'].apply(spacy_entity)

print(df1['new_text'])
```

```
0    [[University of California, ORG], [San Diego, ...
1                          [[MIT, ORG], [Boston, GPE]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = [[1, 'University of California has great research located in San Diego'],[2, 'MIT is at Boston']]
df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['id', 'text'])
df['new_text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: list(nlp(x).ents)) 
print(df["text"])
```